# Copy a list to a binary file

Tags: c, list, file, data-structures

I'm trying to copy the contents of a struct in a list to a binary file.

Here's my structures declarations:

```
typedef struct
{
    char dni[9];
    char nombre[100], apellido[100];
    double deuda;
} t_datos;

struct s_nodo
{
    t_datos dati;
    struct s_nodo *sig;
};
typedef struct s_nodo *t_nodo;
void newfile(t_nodo, FILE *);
```

In the main i fill the list with some data from a .dat file , and looks ok, because if i print the list all is ok.I've got a problem when i try to copy the struct i've in the list to a new binary file.

```
//open and copy old binary file to the list...
fc = fopen("c:\\norep.dat", "w+b");
if (fc == NULL)
{
    puts("Error");
    exit(-1);
}
newfile(lista, fc);
```

Here's my function:

```
void newfile(t_nodo lista, FILE *fc)
{
    if (lista != NULL) 
    {
        fwrite(lista->dati, sizeof(t_datos), 1, fc);
        newfile(lista->sig, fc);
    }
}
```

The error i get is:

> error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'fwrite'|

I know the mistake probably is in the way i'm passing the list to the function, i saw the prototype of fwrite but i don't know how should i fix the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of `fwrite()` must be a pointer (`const void *` *to be precise*), in your case it's not. You have to use `&` the address of operator, like this

```
fwrite(&lista->dati, sizeof(lista->dati), 1, fc);
```

Also, you might want to check the return value of `fwrite()` to be sure that it succeeded, in this case since you are writing a single item it has to be `1`.

**Warning**: don't `typedef` poitners, it might be a problem in the future. And if you must, use some kind of notation like a suffix `_ptr` to indicate that it's a pointer (*libxml-2.0 uses `Ptr` for example*).

Comment: now works great, but i've still some confusion about the use of pointers in this function; in my main i declare lista as:
t_nodo lista=NULL;
and in my struct t_nodo is a pointer to a struct s_nodo, so lista is not a pointer? why i have to add the & operator?

Comment: You are confused because you `typedef`ed it. A pointer must have a `*` near the identifier when declared, that's good. `t_datos` is not a pointer, it's an alias for the anonymous `struct` you use to store the data. `t_datos *dati` would make `dati` a pointer. But then you will need `malloc()` to allocate space for it.